# Print layout will not open in QGIS 3.16

Tags: qgis

[image]I just updated to QGIS 3.16 (Hannover).  I open the Layout Manager (in the Project menu) and tried to Create an Empty Layout.  A dialog box opens up entitled "Create Print Layout", but the box is empty and nothing else happens.  In previous versions, the Layout window would open automatically.  I have no idea what do to.  Hoping someone can help.

Comment: And is there a message saying "Enter a unique print layout title"? Than do that. You have to name it before. Not sure what version you used before and if that wasn't the case there. If it is not like I say, restart your machine and QGIS and if the problem persists, post a screenshot of your "Create Print Layout" box.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  The "Enter a unique print layout title" does not appear, though now that you mention it, I do recall that in my previous version (I think it was 3.14).  I've restarted the machine and QGIS, and the issue persists.  I added a screen shot as you suggested.

Comment: Could it be the box "Enter a unique print layout title" is hidden somewhere, maybe at the margin or out of the visible screen? If you simply hit `ENTER`, does it solve the problem? Otherwise try not using Layout manager, but simply use `Menu Project / New print layout` or `CTRL-P`. If still no success: after re-starting QGIS with a reduced window size (not fullscreen), create a complete new, empty QGIS project and try it there.

Comment: I did indeed trying hitting enter.  Nothing happened there.  I had tried, as you say, bypassing the Layout Manager.  I did not know about ctrl-p, but I tried that.  Both of these produced the same behavior, the empty Create Print Layout dialog box appears.  I noticed that the folder QGIS3 > profiles > default > composer_templates is empty.  I'm not sure if that would explain it.

Comment: Strange, indeed. Maybe the installation is not correct? Did you install the last point release? Standalone installer or OSGeo4w Network installation? Of course, re-installing could be an option, but with no guarantee that it will work. You could also try QGIS 3.18 Zürich.

Comment: I don't see that 'enter a unique print layout title' box hiding anywhere.  If it's there, I'm missing it.

Comment: Yeah, I might just try 3.18.  Or just reinstalling.  I'm definitely stumped.

Comment: 2 other possibilities to debug: 1) create a new profile and try again to create your layout from this new profile 2) try to run qgis with command line option `--defaultui` to be sure you are resetting your GUI and try to create the new layout again.

Comment: What you do is "New from template" - did you try `Menu Project / New print layout`, avoiding Layout manager?

Comment: I did try the New Print Layout directly from the Project Menu, and it produced the same issue.  I have heard people talk about creating 'profiles'.  I'm not sure what 'profile' refers to.  But I guess I can probably look that up.  I don't want to take up too much of your time with beginner questions.

Comment: For profile, https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#working-with-user-profiles

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: I do now notice something I hadn't.  In Layout Manager, there is a section entitled "Open Template Directory".  There are two choices: 'User' and 'Default'  For me 'Default' is greyed out, and I can only select user.  But there are no user layout templates.  I think  want Default.  But as I say, it's greyed out.

Comment: Unrelated IMHO. I have also the same 'Default' is greyed out and "no user layout templates" but no issue.

Comment: I'm stuck.  I installed 3.18, and get the same thing.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm about to have to call it quits for now.  I can add one more thing.   I went to create a new profile, and the "New Profile name" dialog came up.  It was empty.  I'm thinking I need to wipe qgis from my machine (if I can) and start over.

Comment: Try via conda e.g https://gisunchained.wordpress.com/2019/05/29/using-qgis-from-conda/ + https://twitter.com/AlexNetoGeo/status/1394775005532237828 for instruction line for QGIS 3.16

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124735/discussion-on-question-by-jason-print-layout-will-not-open-in-qgis-3-16).

Comment: Hey guys.  Wanted to let you know, the issue is resolved.  Under Settings < Interface Customization < Widgets, I had some widget turned off.  I recently took an online training, and we had been playing around with the Interface Customization.  I turned everything back on (the way it was prior to playing around), and it's working.  Thought I would let you know.  Thank to both of you for your help.  And thank you Mapperz for letting me know about chat.  I thought the resolution was appropriate to include in the comments.